# What is the naming convention for YARN containers used by Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, naming-conventions, hadoop-yarn

When running Spark jobs on top of YARN (yarn-cluster mode), YARN creates the workers in containers that have a name that looks something like this: `container_e116_1495951495692_11203_01_000105`

What is the naming convention for the containers?

Here is my educated guess:

- **container** - Just a constant string, obviously
- **e116** - No Idea what this is. Maybe something to do with the YARN version.
- **1495951495692_11203** - The application-id
- **01** - An attempt counter?
- **000105** - This is probably just an increment integer.

If there is any concrete information about this (or even a refference to the right place in the code), I'd be glad to hear about it.

In light of the above, when running a Spark job on YARN, How can I know which containers belong to which executor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ContainerId.html

A string representation of containerId. The format is container_e*epoch*_*clusterTimestamp*_*appId*_*attemptId*_*containerId* when epoch is larger than 0 (e.g. container_e17_1410901177871_0001_01_000005). *epoch* is increased when RM restarts or fails over. When epoch is 0, epoch is omitted (e.g. container_1410901177871_0001_01_000005).

Answer (score 3):

`containerId` string format is changed if RM restarts with work-preserving recovery enabled. It used to be such format:
`Container_{clusterTimestamp}_{appId}_{attemptId}_{containerId}`
e.g.: `Container_1410901177871_0001_01_000005`.

It is now changed to:
`Container_e{epoch}_{clusterTimestamp}_{appId}_{attemptId}_{containerId}`
e.g.: `Container_e17_1410901177871_0001_01_000005`.

Here, the additional epoch number is a monotonically increasing integer which starts from 0 and is increased by 1 each time RM restarts. If epoch number is 0, it is omitted and the `containerId` string format stays the same as before.